# Подсчёт количества скобок в строке

Tags: c, алгоритм, строки

Имеется код:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
  int n = 0, i, j, len, k;
  char st[81];
  char br[] = "{}[]()<>";
  int br_size = sizeof(br);
  puts("Input string ");
  gets(st);
  len = strlen(st);
  for(i=0; i<=len; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<br_size; j++){
                if (st[i] == br[j]){
                        n++;
                        for (k = j; k<br_size-1; k++){          //Удаление элемента из массива скобок
                                br[k] = br[k+1];                     
                        }
                                br_size--;
                                j--;
                }
        }
  }
  printf("\nBraces = %d", n);
  puts("\nPress any key ... ");
  getch();
}
```

Задача - посчитать количество скобок в строке. Однако на выходе при любом вводе 9 выдаёт. В чём проблема? И еще вопрос, как посчитать количество скобок разного вида, т.е. если в строке встретится (), то чтобы это за 1 считалось

Comment: Если БЫ вы встретили какую-то скобку - то такую же больше не нужно считать? (Просто иначе зачем вы удаляете найденную скобку из строки скобок?) Ну и потом, если уж нашли БЫ - то переходите сразу к следующему символу, к чему проверять дальше? БЫ - потому что вы вообще не смотрите на скобки, а сравниваете только символы из введенной строки: `(st[i] == st[j])`

Comment: Harry, извиняюсь. Ошибся, что проверял одну строку. Надо  st[i] == br[j]. Но всё равно, даже при вводе строки без скобок, где-то находит одну скобку. Что не так?  А задача - посчитать количество разных скобок, поэтому уже использованные удалял

Comment: Сделали бы через битовые массивы, всё бы свелось лишь к подсчёту hweight.

Answer (score 1):

Да все просто...
Если у вас там действительно равнение с `br[j]`, то смотрите - вы выполняете сравнение до какого?

```
for(i=0; i<=len; i++){
```

ага, до символа `st[strlen(st)]`, каковой есть завершающий нулевой символ...

А с другой стороны,

```
int br_size = sizeof(br);
```

для строки в качестве инициализатора также включает нулевой символ. Т.е. вы опять же сравниваете все до последнего нулевого символа:

```
for (j = 0; j<br_size; j++){
```

Вот вам и совпадение в строке без скобок - совпадают нулевые символы...

Еще раз - я что-то не понимаю, зачем вы при этом выбрасываете найденный символ из `br` - вам нужно количество *разных* скобок?

Comment: Harry, совершенно верно, разных

Answer (score 1):

У двух ЛЮБЫХ строк в си есть один общий символ, это символ конца строки, ASCII-код которго равен 0. Исключите его и все будет работать. Просто выводите то же, но вычитайте 1